# Finding polygons in geo_shape query elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, geospatial

I am trying to search documents that have polygons intersecting given lat/lon. Here is my mapping

```
{
    index:"domains",
    type:"land",
    body:{
        properties:{
                landId:{
                    type:"integer"
                },
                name:{
                    type:"string"
                },
                location:{
                    type:"geo_shape"
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how I have indexed the documents

```
{
    landId:1,
    name:"My Test location ",
    location:{
        type:"polygon",
        coordinates: [[
            [-90.4321575,41.4854342],
            [-90.4318142,41.469615],
            [-90.4138756,41.4697436],
            [-90.4139614,41.4855628],
            [-90.4321575,41.4854342]
        ]]
    }
```

}

Here is my query

```
var query = {
   "index":"domains",
   "type":"lands",
   "match_all":{},
    "geo_shape": {
    "location": {
     "relation": "intersects",
     "shape": {
        "type":   "point",
         "coordinates":[-90.4244328,41.4794542]
        }
      } 
    }
}

return esClient.search(query).then(function(resp){
  console.log("**** GOT RESPONSE from Search ****")
  console.log(resp.hits);
    return resp.hits.hits[0]._source;

}),function (err) {
    console.trace(err.message);
}
  ;
```

If I specify index/type in the query I don't get any result and if I don't specify then I get all the documents irrespective of the filter I have added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query you have the type wrong, it should be `land` and not `lands` according to your mapping:

```
var query = {
   "index":"domains",
   "type":"land",
   "body": {
     "query":{
       "geo_shape": {
         "location": {
          "relation": "intersects",
          "shape": {
            "type":   "point",
            "coordinates":[-90.4244328,41.4794542]
          }
         } 
       }
     }
   }
};
```

Comment: Thanks Val, I tried that but still no results. Also if I don't specify any index or type and provide just the query then I get everything that also is little confusing to me.

Comment: I've modified the query which contained a few typos, please try again.

Comment: Thanks, it works ... appreciate your help, so the missing piece was putting the query in "body" tag?

Comment: It did, thanks a ton. Sometime we need fresh set of eyes :-)